# Using views to overwrite Taxonomy pages for content *and* user terms?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, users, views

First: I'm developing a site on a site-wide Drupal 7 installation. It's not quite vanilla Drupal, but I can't add modules to it.

What I'm trying to do: Use views to create a team directory. The taxonomy is associated with users, whom check off the teams they are on. I have a directory page that with a user table that links to the taxonomy terms.

Second: We have taxonomies associated with content and would like to display a table list of all content with those terms, overwriting the standard view for taxonomy pages.

I've created two views - one (Content) view that overwrites /taxonomy/terms/% and displays the table of content terms using a contextual filter on taxonomy term IDs.

The other is essentially the same - one (User) view that overwrites /taxonomy/terms/% and displays the users with that term associated with them.

Making two separate views was the only way I could find to access both User fields and Content fields. I'm hoping there's a way to have them both work but only when the term meets the correct criteria, otherwise the one vocabulary shows blank pages when the other works, or vice versa.

Am I close or off the mark? I seem to be able to get one or the other to work, and they both work in preview mode.